# wordpress unyson установка расширений оффлайн

Tags: wordpress

Доброго дня!

Проблемка.. Скорее с доступом к репозиториям.. Но)

Есть у меня скачанный репозиторий и unyson и page-builder.
И если unyson можно просто подложить в каталог wp-content/plugins для установки оффлайн, то для установки отдельных его расширений - уже нет.

После закидывания в каталог unyson/framework/extensions установка начинается, но приводит к ошибке:

> Не удается активировать расширение Построитель , так как оно не
>   установлено.

Вопрос: как можно установить расширения unyson оффлайн?

Comment: Почему не спросить у его разработчиков? Неужели ты веришь, что велика вероятность найти тут того, кто этот плаг использовал да ещё офлайн, да ещё разбирался с ним? (А вообще, если плаг для активации требует внешние сервисы - фтопку такой плаг)

Comment: @SeVlad, Хорошая мысль, что-то не подумал) Вероятность мала, но вдруг кто-нибудь.. Плаг-то хороший, функциональный, но с установкой расширений доступ к сети - это, конечно, перебор)

Comment: Написал разработчикам.. Ждём-с..